# Uploadify not firing after Tab Change

Tags: asp.net, uploadify

Uploadify script does not fire after tab change, so I get regular `asp:FileUpload` which allows me only one file interaction

Any suggestions to fix it ?

Here is the script;

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function () {
        $("#<%=FileUpload1.ClientID %>").fileUpload({
            'uploader': 'scripts/uploader.swf',
            'cancelImg': 'images/cancel.png',
            'buttonText': 'Browse Files',
            'script': 'Upload.ashx',
            'folder': 'uploads',
            'fileDesc': 'Image Files',
            'fileExt': '*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.gif;*.png',
            'multi': true,
            'auto': true
        });
    });
</script>
```

---

Here is the tab definitions,

```
<asp:TabContainer ID="tabMyHome" runat="server"
                  ActiveTabIndex="0"
                  CssClass="MyTabStyle"
                  AutoPostBack="True">
     <asp:TabPanel ID="tabRecent" runat="server"
                   HeaderText="Recent Activity"
                   Width="100%">
     </asp:TabPanel>
</asp:TabContainer>
```

Comment: corrected tags (it's not c#, it's asp.net)

Comment: you are calling `this.FileUpload1.ClientID` in your javascript-example - but i cannot find it in the asp.net/html excerpt ...

Answer (score 0):

At a guess I'd say that when you change the tab you are adding a new fileupload that is different to the one that was present on the page load and wont have the filupload events attached to it.

You may need to reapply the `.fileUpload` in the tabcontainers client side `OnClientActiveTabChanged` event

Comment: That might be it,
But truth is I am kind a beginner, Can you be more specific on 
How to reapply .fileUpload

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it using following code

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
<ContentTemplate>
<script type="text/javascript">
    Sys.Application.add_init(function () {
        $("#<%=FileUpload1.ClientID %>").fileUpload({
            'uploader': 'scripts/uploader.swf',
            'cancelImg': 'images/cancel.png',
            'buttonText': 'Browse Files',
            'script': 'Upload.ashx',
            'folder': 'uploads',
            'fileDesc': 'Image Files',
            'fileExt': '*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.gif;*.png',
            'multi': true,
            'auto': true
        });
    });
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);
    function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
        $("#<%=FileUpload1.ClientID %>").fileUpload({
            'uploader': 'scripts/uploader.swf',
            'cancelImg': 'images/cancel.png',
            'buttonText': 'Browse Files',
            'script': 'Upload.ashx',
            'folder': 'uploads',
            'fileDesc': 'Image Files',
            'fileExt': '*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.gif;*.png',
            'multi': true,
            'auto': true
        });
    }                
 </script>
```